# How do i use a loop to delete columns in a data frame?

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

My code:

```
SMI_Mly$V1 <- NULL
SMI_Mly$V2 <- NULL
SMI_Mly$V3 <- NULL
SMI_Mly$V4 <- NULL
...
SMI_Mly$V10 <- NULL
```

I am sure there is a better and shorter way to delete all these columns from the dataframe. Maybe by using a loop? Can someone please show me how to do it?

Comment: `SMI_Mly[paste0("V", c(1:10))] <- NULL`, please also consider to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) Tim's answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may use an appropriate subset here:

```
cols <- paste0("V", c(1:10))
indices <- sapply(cols, function(x) { grep(x, names(df)) })
SMI_Mly[, -indices]
```

The above call to `sapply` generates the positional indices of the columns `V1` to `V10` which you wish to exclude from your data frame.  Then, we may use subset notation to exclude those columns.